# merge every other row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe where the id and values are on two alternating rows.

```
278             
8134134 87903   98732   1248    
9907        
3134 1450893    1345807 1234    555    
23              
23487   12347   3407
```

I am trying to append the values to the ids so they are on the same row.

```
278 8134134 87903   98732   1248    
9907    3134    1450893 1345807 1234    555    
23  23487   12347   3407
```

(Also wondering how to format tables in these questions!)

Comment: Can you do `dput(df)`? Not clear if odd and even rows have same "name"

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your data structure really looks like.  I've taken my best guess.  In principle, you can get alternate rows using a `c(TRUE, FALSE)` index and relying on recycling.

```
df <- 
  data.frame(x = c("278",
                   "8134134 87903 98732 1248",
                   "9907",
                   "3134 1450893 1345807 1234 555",
                   "23",
                   "23487 12347 3407"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cbind(df[c(TRUE, FALSE), ],
      df[c(FALSE, TRUE), ])
```

Comment: It's for twitter, so row 1 is the twitter user id, row 2 is who they follow and it follows that pattern. So odd rows are alway 1 value and the even rows could be any number of values.